# VS code Não Autocompleta tags html ou css em uma Blade laravel

Tags: visual-studio-code

Estou utilizando o Vs code para editar códigos HTM,CSS,PHP. quando eu edito um código com extensão  .html e digito as tags de html ou css, ela autocompleta mostrando as opções de comando normalmente.
Já quando esse código é realizado em uma blade no laravel, exemplo principal.blade.php  o autocomplete não funciona.
Isso acontece só no vscode, no eclipse por exemplo funciona perfeitamente.
Alguém tem uma dica pra essa função funcionar:

Comment: Eu marquei como duplicada, porque a minha resposta na outra pergunta serve para os dois casos. Você pode adicionar `"files.associations": { "*.blade.php" : "html" }` ou `"emmet.includeLanguages": {"blade":"html"}` no seu `settings.json`.

Answer (score -4):

Tem extensões próprias para Laravel e blade no VSCode, mas acridto que a extensão [Laravel Extension Pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=onecentlin.laravel-extension-pack) resolva isso e ainda adicione mais facilidades no seu VSCode para trabalhar com Laravel.